# ASP.NET Global.asax Application_Error works but not when using the Error event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is supposed to catch all unhandled exceptions within the global.asax application error handler.

If I define the handler as follows:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

then it works fine.  However, if within the Application_Start event I try and do:

```
this.Error += new EventHandler(Application_Error);
```

The actual event is never called.

Does anyone know why and if so what i'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to add to the error event explicitly; Application_Error should get called automatically by the framework.

Comment: I'll up vote this for the first comment,  but I don't believe the second part is true, I'm currently running my application with out the CustomErrors element in my webconfig and it's hitting the Error handler fine.

Comment: Thanks, not sure where I go that from .  Edited my response.

Answer (score 0):

The event is not being called either because Exceptions are being caught somewhere else in the application (and swallowed maybe) or because you are registering the event in the Application_Start event (not needed). You want to do something like this in your Application_Error:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
  // log exception
  // Email exception
}
```

I use this method to both log and E-mail uncaught errors for all my applications. Hope this helps.